# Applets do not work in Internet Explorer 11 [2018-07]

Tags: windows-7, java, internet-explorer, java-applet, applet

**System:**

**OS:** fresh installed Windows 7 64 bit (with all updates installed).

**Browser:** Internet Explorer 11 32 bit

**Java:** 8 SE, 32 bit, build 181 (latest for now)

CPU: Intel C2D

IE Java plugin is activated

**Symptoms:**
Applets are not loading. I checked this with few sites:

- https://www.w3.org/People/mimasa/test/object/java/clock
- https://javatester.org/version.html
- http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~tway/toys/fartomatic/player.html
- https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp

Java seems activated in these places:

- In IE: Internet Options -> Security -> Custom Level -> Scripting -> Scripting of Java applets = Enabled.
- In Windows Control Panel: Configure Java / Java Control Panel -> Security -> Enable Java content for browser and Webstart applications

I made few restarts because I expected that they did not help.

Any assumptions will be highly appreciated.

Activating a console that could show what the problem is will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/ie_tips.xml

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks but that points seems to be old and they do not solve the problem now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45423357/ie-11-cant-find-java-plugin-to-run-applet?noredirect=1&lq=1 - seems to have good ideas (and maybe partial solution), but it didnt helped me

Answer (score 0):

*This is not a solution for IE, so I wait for an solution for it.*

As a workaround, clients could install an older version of FF, Firefox Extended Support Release (ESR **52**), where applets support is still not removed.

I have been told that Google Chrome also has such old version with extended support